# While converting classic notes to Lightning enhanced Content Notes getting UNSAFE_HTML_CONTENT error on versionData field.!

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, contentversion, notes, contentnote

We are migrating from Classic to Lightning, In this process we are converting classic Notes to Lightning supported Note (ContentVersion). 
We have a batch which does this job, getting below error:

**UNSAFE_HTML_CONTENT, Note can't be saved because it contains HTML tags or unescaped characters that are not allowed in a Note.: [VersionData]**

I am using below snippet for escaping html characters, Please let me know if you have faced the similar challenges while doing so:

```
String noteBody= noteBody<ClassicNoteBody>.replace('&', 'sfdcAMPERSANDsfdc').escapeXml().replace('sfdcAMPERSANDsfdc', '&amp;').replace('&apos;', '&#39;').replace('©', '&copy;').replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;').replace('\'','&#39;').replace('"','&quot;').replace('\r\n', '<br>').replace('\r', '<br>') .replace('\n', '<br>');
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.versionData = Blob.valueOf(noteBody);
```

Comment: is it possible to have more then one of any special character?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. 
replace(target, replacement)
Replaces each substring of a string that matches the literal target sequence target with the specified literal replacement sequence replacement.
Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm